# OUTSIDE border only to text which spans multiple lines

Tags: html, css

How to achieve an outside border only on text of any length which could span multiple lines, must be responsive.

Looking for styling similar to below image.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far, struggling with top border and responsiveness over screen sizes and using various font sizes, the best I've got, might be going about this all wrong though:

http://www.cssdesk.com/7nxBa

Making text smaller shows overlapping right border, making text LARGER shows top border...

[image: smaller text]

[image: larger text]

Comment: You need to demonstrate your research and show us what you've tried. As it stands now your question reads as a 'write my code for me' request. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck.

Comment: sorry, it's been a while since I posted, forgot the 'rules', will update question with what I've got so far... thanks for any help.

Comment: Ideally I'd like pure CSS, but if a solution isn't possible then would accept jQuery and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the 'outline' css attribute which seems to work perfectly for my needs.

```css
.container {
  font: 3rem sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
  
.highlight {
  display: inline;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000; 
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
    outline: 0.4rem solid #000;
}

html,body {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="highlight">
      I think I cracked<br>
      it<br>
      using the 'outline' css property, seems to do the trick
      ;-)
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```